# How to deduce two sets are equal when one being subset of another is proven?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Below is a proof that $(A \cap B ) \cup (A \setminus B) = A$:

Let's consider $x \in (A \cap B ) \cup (A \setminus B)$.

1. $ x ∈ (A∩B)∨x ∈ (A \setminus B) $
2. $ x ∈ A∧x ∈ B)∨(x ∈ A∧ x \notin B) $
3. $ x ∈ A∧(x ∈ B∨x \notin B) $

Which means $ x ∈ A $ and thus $ (A∩B)∪(A \setminus B) = A.  $

---

The proof evidently shows that $ (A∩B)∪(A \setminus B) ⊂ A $ but why does it show the two are equal?

Comment: Two ways : either 1) each step is an **iff** ($\leftrightarrow$), or 2) show the reverse inclusion : $A \subset \ldots$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Doesn't it matter that A is a single group that is present in the union on the left side? If I was to prove this, I would show that $ A⊂ .... $ but this proof doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

The proof should look more like this:

\begin{align*}
& x \in (A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B) \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad& \left( x\in (A\cap B)\right) \vee \left(x\in (A\setminus B)\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad& \left( x\in A \wedge x\in B\right) \vee \left(x\in A \wedge X \notin B\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad& x\in A \wedge \left(x\in B \vee X \notin B\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad& x\in A \wedge \mathrm{true} \\
\Longleftrightarrow\quad& x\in A.
\end{align*}

Since each step is an equivalence, you can read it top to bottom to get $\subset$ and bottom to top to get $\supset$.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to rewrite the $\setminus$ as complement and use a [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra):

$
(A \cap B ) \cup (A \setminus B)
= (A \cap B ) \cup  (A \cap B^C)
= A \cap  (B \cup B^C)
= A
$

Comment: Using the notation $B^{\mathrm C}$ requires a universe $U$ so that $B^{\mathrm C}= U\setminus B$. The distributive law does not need this change in notation though: $A\setminus B= A \cap (A\setminus B)$ achieves the same.